# how to get a work date in a month using carbon?

Tags: database, laravel, php-carbon

I Want to get a work date in a month using carbon in Laravel,
for Example in March 2020, i want get all of date from March 2020 without weekend(Saturday and Sunday) date,
Like this,

```
2020-03-02
2020-03-03
2020-03-04
2020-03-05
2020-03-06 

2020-03-09
2020-03-10 
2020-03-11
2020-03-12
2020-03-13

2020-03-16
2020-03-17
2020-03-18
2020-03-19
2020-03-20

2020-03-23
2020-03-24
2020-03-25
2020-03-26
2020-03-27

2020-03-30
2020-03-31
```

it's Possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helpful...

```
    $month = '2020-03';
    $start = Carbon\Carbon::parse($month)->startOfMonth();
    $end = Carbon\Carbon::parse($month)->endOfMonth();

    $dates = [];
    while ($start->lte($end)) {
        $carbon = Carbon\Carbon::parse($start);
        if ($carbon->isWeekend() !=true) { 
            $dates[] = $start->copy()->format('Y-m-d');
        }
        $start->addDay();
    }

    foreach ($dates as $key => $dateval) {
        echo "<br>".$dateval;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using PHP as below:

```
$workdays = array();
$type = CAL_GREGORIAN;
$month = date('n'); // Month ID, 1 through to 12.
$year = date('Y'); // Year in 4 digit 2009 format.
$day_count = cal_days_in_month($type, $month, $year); // Get the amount of days

//loop through all days
for ($i = 1; $i <= $day_count; $i++) {

        $date = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$i; //format date
        $get_name = date('l', strtotime($date)); //get week day
        $day_name = substr($get_name, 0, 3); // Trim day name to 3 chars

        //if not a weekend add day to array
        if($day_name != 'Sun' && $day_name != 'Sat'){
            $workdays[] = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($i."-".$month."-".$year));
        }

}

print_r($workdays);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2020-03-02
    [1] => 2020-03-03
    [2] => 2020-03-04
    [3] => 2020-03-05
    [4] => 2020-03-06
    [5] => 2020-03-09
    [6] => 2020-03-10
    [7] => 2020-03-11
    [8] => 2020-03-12
    [9] => 2020-03-13
    [10] => 2020-03-16
    [11] => 2020-03-17
    [12] => 2020-03-18
    [13] => 2020-03-19
    [14] => 2020-03-20
    [15] => 2020-03-23
    [16] => 2020-03-24
    [17] => 2020-03-25
    [18] => 2020-03-26
    [19] => 2020-03-27
    [20] => 2020-03-30
    [21] => 2020-03-31
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` method to apply Carbon's `isWeekday()` to a date period:

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::between('2020-03-01', '2020-03-31')->filter('isWeekday');
foreach ($period as $date) {
  $days[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
echo implode('<br>', $days);
```

This will print out

```
2020-03-02
2020-03-03
2020-03-04
2020-03-05
2020-03-06
2020-03-09
2020-03-10
2020-03-11
2020-03-12
2020-03-13
2020-03-16
2020-03-17
2020-03-18
2020-03-19
2020-03-20
2020-03-23
2020-03-24
2020-03-25
2020-03-26
2020-03-27
2020-03-30
2020-03-31
```

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period